# What death scenes do these pictures belong to?

Tags: game-of-thrones

There is **[this](http://beautifuldeath.com/)** beautiful website depicting the deaths occurring in the Game Of Thrones series. I understood most of them, but there are some which I am unable to find. Could someone tell me which deaths are being talked about in:

- Season 1 x Episode 3 [image]
- Season 2 x Episode 2 [image]
- Season 2 x Episode 4 [image]
- Season 3 x Episode 2 [image]
- Season 3 x Episode 7 [image]

It would be great if you could list all the deaths, so that I can make sure I'm thinking about the right ones.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a list question

Comment: What about just the explanations for the ones that I didn't understand? There are not many.

Comment: @Liath - its not a list question in the sense that it has an open ended list of possible answers, with no chance of a 'best' answer to be accepted.  There are 5 pictures depicting events.  Don't think its a very interesting question however (sorry).

Comment: Agreed that it is not a very interesting question, but I couldn't find answers elsewhere, so I asked it here.

Comment: @iandotkelly thanks for the clarification. Aksh, I don't suggest you start spamming but perhaps if you were to select one of the scenes you're particularity curious about it would be a better fit? Where did X die?

Comment: While it says it celebrates iconic deaths, the 3 eyed raven is what appears to Bran in his dream while in a coma. Also, the game of thrones wiki for this episode lists no deaths occurring. Also checked S2E2 wikia and that lists no deaths, unless you count the head in the saddlebag.

Comment: My problem with the question is that it will become worthless when the linked website goes down. At least include a description of the picture for the death you are looking for.

Comment: I agree. No need to close. Just adding a description of the poster should be fine I think.

Comment: I added pictures from the site so that the question can stand alone without looking up to the website mentioned. @Liath, I could not figure out the deaths mentioned in the above pictures even after specifically watching the episodes for them multiple times. So I added them. Surely 5 pictures don't count as spamming?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Season 1 x Episode 3** Not entirely sure. No one died in that episode and the picture of the Three Eyed Crow is a reference to the Bran story line. Perhaps it is about the revelation that Bran can never walk or climb again, so perhaps the death of Bran the Climber?

**Season 2 x Episode 2** Refers to the (supposed) death of Craster's baby who has left out for the White Walkers.

**Season 2 x Episode 4** Refers to the dead Lannister soldiers following their defeat at the hands of Robb Stark.

**Season 3 x Episode 2** Another cryptic one. The quote "You hear them, boy? The Old Gods are answering you." is once again indicative of Bran's story. That same episode Robb and his mother receive the false news that Bran and Rickon are dead. Hoster Tully (Catelyn's father) was also announced dead in this episode.

**Season 3 x Episode 7** No deaths in this episode. However the picture is that of a sept, and that points me to Sansa's marriage to Tyrion. So I'm guessing the death of Sansa's hopes of being rid of the Lannisters.

---

**Update**

Feeling in a particularly procrastanating mood (and the pictures really are beautiful) I decided to do the rest. Will probably keep updating as new ones are revealed.

**Season 1 x Episode 1** The execution of the deserter Will at the hands of Ned Stark.

**Season 1 x Episode 2** The death of the cook's boy Mycah at the hands of the Sandor Clegane.

**Season 1 x Episode 2 II** The death of Lady at the hands of Ned Stark.

**Season 1 x Episode 4** The death of Ser Hugh of the Vale at the hands of the Gregor Clegane.

**Season 1 x Episode 5** The death of Jory Cassel at the hands of Jaime Lannister.

**Season 1 x Episode 6** The death of Viserys Targaryen at the hands of Khal Drogo.

**Season 1 x Episode 7** The death of King Robert Baratheon at the tusks of a wild boar. Don't drink and hunt boar people!

**Season 1 x Episode 8** The death of the stable boy at the hands of Arya Stark.

**Season 1 x Episode 9** The death of Ned Stark at the hands of Ser Ilyn Payne.

**Season 1 x Episode 10** The death of Khal Drogo at the hands of Mirri Maz Duur and Daenerys Targaryen

---

**Season 2 x Episode 1** The death of Maester Cressen by his own hands and Melisandre's poker face.

**Season 2 x Episode 3** The death of Yoren at the hands of the Lannister men.

**Season 2 x Episode 5** The death of King Renly Baratheon at the hands of the Shadow Baby.

**Season 2 x Episode 6** The death of Ser Amory Lorch at the hands of Jaqen H'ghar.

**Season 2 x Episode 7** The death of the Thirteen of Qarth at the hands of Xaro and Pyat Pree.

**Season 2 x Episode 8** The death of the Lannister guards at the hands of Jaqen H'ghar.

**Season 2 x Episode 9** The death of hundreds (thousands?) of Stannis' men in the battle of the Black Water.

**Season 2 x Episode 10** The death of Pyat Pree at the hands (fires?) of Dany's baby dragons.

**Season 3 x Episode 1** The death of the Northern captives at the orders of Gregor Clegane.

**Season 3 x Episode 3** The death of several Night's Watchmen at the hands of the White Walkers.

**Season 3 x Episode 4** The death of Kraznys and the Good Masters of Astapor at the hands of Dany's toddler dragons.

**Season 3 x Episode 5** The death of Rickard Karstark at the hands of Robb Stark.

**Season 3 x Episode 6** The death of Ros at the hands of King Joffrey Baratheon.

**Season 3 x Episode 8** The death of the White Walker at the hands of Samwell "The Slayer" Tarly.

**Season 3 x Episode 9** The death of Robb Stark, Catelyen Stark, pretty much all of their remaining men, and the ears of anyone sitting next to a non-book reader watching the Red Wedding for the first time at the hands of the Lannisters, the Freys and the Boltons.

**Season 3 x Episode 10** The death of a bunch of unlucky Frey guardsmen at the hands of Arya Stark and Sandor Clegane.

---

**Season 4 x Episode 1** The death of Poliver and his men at the hands of Arya Stark and Col. Sandor Clegane.

Comment: Another good answer to a bad question. Nice save.

Comment: It was a bit inappropriate of me to ask for the list of all the deaths, but the ones that I specifically listed were driving me mad. I watched the episodes multiple times, still couldn't figure them out. Thank you @SystemDown!

Comment: 1.03 could be the death of Bran's assassin.

Comment: @Joey - But that happened in 1.02, and besides the text and image don't really match up.

Answer (score 7):

I have grouped each episode by link of `| beautiful death picture | victim | killer |` and `reference quotes`*(if any)*. I took photos from [Game of Thrones Facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/GameOfThrones) and used information from [GOTwikia](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Game_of_Thrones_Wiki).

## [Season 1](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Season_1)

- [Episode 1 (Winter Is Coming)](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Winter_is_Coming)

  [BeautifulDeath picture](https://fbcdn-sphotos-b-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn2/t1.0-9/1604844_10152040741632734_342501291_n.jpg) | [Will](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Will) | [Eddard Stark](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Eddard_Stark)

  > **Ned** : In the name of Robert of the house Baratheon, first of his name, King
  >   of the Andals and the First Men, Lord of the Seven Kingdoms and
  >   Protector of the realm, I Eddard of house Stark, Lord of Winterfell
  >   and Warden of the North, sentence you to die.

---

- [Episode 2 (The Kingsroad)](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/The_Kingsroad)

  [BeautifulDeath picture](https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/t1.0-9/10014667_10152040741757734_1553383855_n.jpg) | [Mycah](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Mycah) | [Hound](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Sandor_Clegane)

  > **Ned** : The butcher's boy; you rode him down?
  >
  > **Hound** : He ran. Not very fast.

---

- [Episode 3 (Lord Snow)](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Lord_Snow)

  [BeautifulDeath picture](https://fbcdn-sphotos-g-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn2/v/t1.0-9/1185484_10152040741897734_1890173584_n.jpg?oh=0693951c1c1bd8640e0ea9923bfd5f64&oe=53BE51C1&__gda__=1406820343_0b7009b38ad016d859ba2b65c99d7097) | There were no deaths [ravens told us that](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10152040741897734&set=a.10152040741337734.1073741857.74133697733&type=3&theater)

---

- [Episode 4 (Cripples, Bastards and Broken Things)](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Cripples,_Bastards_and_Broken_Things)

  [BeautifulDeath picture](https://scontent-b-fra.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-frc1/t1.0-9/1975203_10152040742017734_448722050_n.jpg) | [Ser Hugh of the Vale](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Hugh_of_the_Vale) | [The Mountain](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Gregor_Clegane)

  > **Littlefinger** : Ser Hugh of the Vale, he was Jon Arryn's squire. Look how far he has   come.

---

- [Episode 5 (The Wolf and the Lion)](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/The_Wolf_and_the_Lion)

  [BeautifulDeath picture](https://fbcdn-sphotos-g-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-frc3/t1.0-9/1921896_10152040741422734_538106233_n.jpg) | [Jory Cassel](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Jory_Cassel) | [Jaime Lannister](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Jaime_Lannister)

  > **Ned** : You kill me, your brother's a dead man
  >
  > **Jaime** : You're right. Take him alive. Kill his men.

---

- [Episode 6 (A Golden Crown)](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/A_Golden_Crown)

  [BeautifulDeath picture](https://scontent-a-fra.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-frc3/t1.0-9/10003971_10152040741417734_1344898493_n.jpg) | [Viserys Targaryen](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Viserys_Targaryen) | [Drogo](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Drogo)

  > **Daenerys** : He says yes. You shall have a golden crown. That men shall tremble to behold

---

- [Episode 7 (You Win or You Die)](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/You_Win_or_You_Die)

  [BeautifulDeath picture](https://fbcdn-sphotos-a-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-frc1/t1.0-9/1965035_10152040742012734_476767988_n.jpg) | [Robert Baratheon](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Robert_Baratheon) | A boar

  > **Robert** : And I want everyone to taste the boar that got me.

---

- [Episode 8 (The Pointy End)](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/The_Pointy_End)

  [BeautifulDeath picture](https://fbcdn-sphotos-c-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/t1.0-9/148362_10152040741412734_1271598472_n.jpg) | [Arya Stark](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Arya_Stark) | [A Stableboy](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Stableboy)

  > **Jon Sonw** to **Arya** : Stick them with the pointy end [from episode 1]

---

- [Episode 9 (Baelor)](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Baelor)

  [BeautifulDeath picture](https://fbcdn-sphotos-f-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/t1.0-9/1969166_10152040741537734_793998381_n.jpg) | [Eddard Stark](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Eddard_Stark) | [Ser Ilyn Payne](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Ilyn_Payne)

  > **Joffery** : Ser Ilyn, bring me his head.

---

- [Episode 10 (Fire and Blood)](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Fire_and_Blood)

  [BeautifulDeath picture](https://fbcdn-sphotos-d-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/t1.0-9/1549411_10152040741562734_367423946_n.jpg) | [Khal Drogo](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Drogo) | By infection

---

## [Season 2](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Season_2)

- [Episode 1 (The North Remembers)](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/The_North_Remembers)

  [BeautifulDeath picture](https://scontent-b-fra.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-frc1/t1.0-9/1959884_10152057336322734_38145998_n.jpg) | [Cressen](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Cressen) | Poison in his wine

  > **Cressen** : A cup of wine to honor the one true God.

---

- [Episode 2 (The Night Lands)](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/The_Night_Lands)

  [BeautifulDeath picture](https://fbcdn-sphotos-a-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/t1.0-9/1907302_10152057336332734_281522211_n.jpg) | [Caster](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Craster)'s new born boy | [White Walkers](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/White_Walkers)

---

- [Episode 3 (What is Dead May Never Die)](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/What_is_Dead_May_Never_Die)

  [BeautifulDeath picture](https://fbcdn-sphotos-g-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn2/t1.0-9/10153657_10152057336327734_517396194_n.jpg) | [Yoren](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Yoren) | [Amory Lorch](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Amory_Lorch)

  > **Amory** : This is your last chance in the name of king Joffery drop your weapons.
  >
  > **Yoren** : I don't think I will.
  >
  > **Amory** : So be it.

---

- [Episode 4 (Garden of Bones)](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Garden_of_Bones)

  [BeautifulDeath picture](https://fbcdn-sphotos-f-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/t1.0-9/1623266_10152057336417734_397287669_n.jpg) | Lannister soldiers | Robb's soldier

---

- [Episode 5 (The Ghost of Harrenhal)](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/The_Ghost_of_Harrenhal)

  [BeautifulDeath picture](https://scontent-b-fra.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ash4/t1.0-9/1391904_10152057336467734_785794262_n.jpg) | [Renly_Baratheon](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Renly_Baratheon) | [Melisandre](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Melisandre)'s [Devil creature](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Shadow)

  > **Catelyn** : You can't avenge him if you are dead.

---

- [Episode 6 (A Golden Crown)](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/A_Golden_Crown)

  [BeautifulDeath picture](https://fbcdn-sphotos-b-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/t1.0-9/1972542_10152057336472734_1615490167_n.jpg) | [Amory Lorch](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Amory_Lorch) | [Jaqen H'ghar](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Jaqen_H%27ghar)

  > **Arya** : Amory Lorch.
  >
  > **Jaqen H'ghar** : The girl has named a second name. A man will do what must be done.

---

- [Episode 7 (A Man Without Honor)](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/A_Man_Without_Honor)

  [BeautifulDeath picture](https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-frc1/t1.0-9/1959503_10152057336527734_1274494699_n.jpg) | Eleven members of [The Thirteen](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/The_Thirteen) | [Pyat Pree](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Pyat_Pree)

---

- [Episode 8 (The Prince of Winterfell)](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/The_Prince_of_Winterfell)

  [BeautifulDeath picture](https://fbcdn-sphotos-e-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-frc3/t1.0-9/10001481_10152057336642734_2085229418_n.jpg) | Lannister soldiers | [Jaqen H'ghar](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Jaqen_H%27ghar)

  > **Jaqen** : A girl and her friend will walk through the gate at midnight.

---

- [Episode 9 (Blackwater)](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Blackwater_%28episode%29)

  [BeautifulDeath picture](https://fbcdn-sphotos-c-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-frc1/t1.0-9/1978708_10152057336647734_1771518614_n.jpg) | [Stannis Baratheon's army](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Eddard_Stark) | [Tyrion Lyannister](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Ilyn_Payne)

  > **Tyrion** : Those are brave men knocking at our door. Let's go kill them!

---

- [Episode 10 (Valar_Morghulis)](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Valar_Morghulis)

  [BeautifulDeath picture](https://fbcdn-sphotos-a-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-frc1/t1.0-9/1966818_10152057336677734_1740382273_n.jpg) | [Pyat Pree](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Pyat_Pree) | Dragon

  > **Daenerys** : Dracarys!

---

## [Season 3](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Season_3)

- [Episode 1 (Valar Dohaeris)](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Valar_Dohaeris)

  [BeautifulDeath picture](https://fbcdn-sphotos-a-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/t1.0-9/15076_10152075001282734_1189409255_n.jpg) | Northern men | By Greyjoy's madness

  > **Rickard Karstark** : 200 northmen slaughtered like sheep.
  >
  > **Roose Bolton** : The debt will be repaid, my friend.

---

- [Episode 2 (Dark Wings, Dark Words)](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Dark_Wings,_Dark_Words)

  [BeautifulDeath picture](https://fbcdn-sphotos-g-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/t1.0-9/1604823_10152075001432734_1083336382_n.jpg) | No one dies

---

- [Episode 3 (Walk of Punishment)](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Walk_of_Punishment)

  [BeautifulDeath picture](https://fbcdn-sphotos-e-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-frc1/t1.0-9/10153013_10152075003197734_2071503503_n.jpg) | Horses | [White walkers](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/White_Walkers)

---

- [Episode 4 (And Now His Watch is Ended)](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/And_Now_His_Watch_is_Ended)

  [BeautifulDeath picture](https://fbcdn-sphotos-c-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn2/t1.0-9/10170928_10152075005562734_1066089444_n.jpg) | [Kraznys mo Nakloz](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Kraznys_mo_Nakloz) | [Dragon](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Drogon)

  > **Daenerys** : dracarys!

---

- [Episode 4 (Kissed by Fire)](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Kissed_by_Fire)

  [BeautifulDeath picture](https://fbcdn-sphotos-e-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/t1.0-9/66830_10152074999177734_780032440_n.jpg) | [Rickard Karstark](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Rickard_Karstark) | [Robb stark](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Robb_Stark)

  > **Rickard Karstark** : kill me and be cursed.

---

- [Episode 6 (The Climb)](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/The_Climb)

  [BeautifulDeath picture](https://scontent-b-fra.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ash3/t1.0-9/10177887_10152075001107734_1064735649_n.jpg) | [Ros](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Ros) | [Joffrey Baratheon](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Joffrey_Baratheon)

  > **Varys** : Chaos isn't a pit. Chaos is a ladder.

---

- [Episode 7 (The Bear and the Maiden Fair)](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/The_Bear_and_the_Maiden_Fair_%28episode%29)

  [BeautifulDeath picture](https://fbcdn-sphotos-a-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/t1.0-9/10157210_10152074999002734_2032172827_n.jpg) | No one dies

---

- [Episode 8 (Second Sons)](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Second_Sons_%28episode%29)

  [BeautifulDeath picture](https://fbcdn-sphotos-e-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-frc3/t1.0-9/10001481_10152057336642734_2085229418_n.jpg) | [Samwell Tarly](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Samwell_Tarly) | [White Walker](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/White_Walkers)

---

- [Episode 9 (The Rains of Castamere)](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/The_Rains_of_Castamere_%28episode%29)

  [BeautifulDeath picture](https://fbcdn-sphotos-c-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-frc3/t1.0-9/1982138_10152075000217734_756735125_n.jpg) | [Robb Stark](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Robb_Stark), [Talisa Stark](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Talisa_Stark), [Catelyn Stark](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Catelyn_Stark) & [Grey Wind](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Grey_Wind) | [Roose Bolton](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Roose_Bolton)

  > **Roose Bolton** : The Lannisters send their regards.

---

- [Episode 10 (Mhysa)](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Mhysa)

  [BeautifulDeath picture](https://scontent-b-fra.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ash3/t1.0-9/10006914_10152075000507734_1667068841_n.jpg) | [Arya Stark](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Arya_Stark) | Frey men

  > **Arya** : valar morghulis!

Comment: Great minds think alike :)

Comment: I would really like to see these pictures. To bad the hyperlinks don't work.